# How to reconstruct data efficiently - versioned by individual fields, only those changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, versioning, common-table-expression

I have a legacy DB with some Tables being versioned the following way: each field individually - and only those that changed;

```
Table1

ObjID  userID  Data1    Data2  Data3
-----  ------  -----    ----   ---- 
11       1       A      null   123  
222      1       H      111    999
33       2       C      222    333


Table1_ver

ObjID   userID   FieldName    OldValue    VersionNumber
-----  ------     -----        ----        ----
222       1       Data1         F           5
222       1       Data1         A           8
222       1       Data2        888          10
33        8       Data1         G           10
```

the Current Version is stored in some other table - say it's 11 now; when the change happens, the old data value is being recorded along with the "old" version number (the one the old value belonged to), then the version number increases

The tables have many fields (>20) and lots of records, so I guess the initial idea was to use less storage for versioning. Now I need to add functionality to reconstruct the data at a given point in time (by version). How can I do it in an elegant and efficient way - preferably without the dynamic SQL but rather with some set-based approach. Can it be done in SQL with good performance? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconstruct the records.  The query will be a bit cumbersome.  The logic is to do the following  For a given field, the value is given by the following rules:

1. The new value of the record with the next smaller version than @VersionNumber
2. The old value of the record with the next higher version than @VersionNumber
3. The current value

Here is an example (with fewer fields):

```
select t1.objId, t1.userId,
       max(case when tv.FieldName = 'Data1' and VersionNumber < @VersionNumber
                then tv.NewValue
                when tv.FieldName = 'Data1' and VersionNumber > @VersionNumber
                then tv.OldValue
                when tv.FieldName = 'Data1' and VersionNumber is null
                then t.Data1
           end) as Data1,
       max(case when tv.FieldName = 'Data2' and VersionNumber < @VersionNumber
                then tv.NewValue
                when tv.FieldName = 'Data2' and VersionNumber > @VersionNumber
                then tv.OldValue
                when tv.FieldName = 'Data2' and VersionNumber is null
                then t.Data2
           end) as Data2,
      . . . 
from table1 t1 left outer join
     (select tv.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objId, userId, fieldname
                                order by abs(VersionNumber - @VersionNumber)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table_var tv
     ) tv
     on tv.objId = t.objId and tv.userId = t.userId and seqnum = 1
group by t1.objId, t1.userId;
```

One challenge with this logic is being sure that the current value doesn't accidentally mix in the previous values.  The `left outer join` with `seqnum = 1` handles this.  The current value only gets used when there is no match with a preceding or succeeding value.

Comment: wow, this looks awesome! the only problem left - I don't have NewValue field. I tried to modify "tv" table expression, like so -

`select tv.*, tv_new.OldValue as NewValue,
row_number() over (partition by tv.objId, tv.userId, tv.fieldname order by abs(tv.VersionNumber - @VersionNumber)) as seqnum 
 from Table1_ver tv LEFT JOIN Table1_ver tv_new on tv.objId = tv_new.objId where tv.versionNumber <= @VersionNumber and tv_new.versionNumber > tv.versionNumber and tv.fieldname=tv_new.fieldname` 

doesn't work fully yet, I guess I need to repeat the seqnum trick here too.

Comment: some more findings - we can't filter by `where tv.versionNumber <= @VersionNumber` since we need OldValue on fields that were changed later, because that's what they had at the moment. and then - the biggest problem now: if a record has more than one field changed, `group by` kills all the changes but one. example - if I go for version 5, for `ObjID=222` I need to get "F" for Data1 and "888" for Data2; after `group by`, when it's time to pick the values, only one record remains. Is it possible to work around it?

Comment: Thanks again, finally I got it working based on your suggestion - I had to change it here and there to adapt to the particularities of my case, but still - it's working now!